# RegEx for not matching multiple exact strings

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I am looking to limit what a user can input into a field based on previous entries that already exist.

For example, a user has entered these values into the database already:

```
["typescript", "C#", "python"]
```

When they type one of these already existing values into the input field EXACTLY, I want the validator message to appear.

I have this negative look ahead Regex from another answer I found:

```
^(?!.*(typescript|C#|python)).*$
```

but it will fail validation if one of those words appears anywhere in the input string (for example: "pythons" would fail). I just want it to fail if one of those words appear exactly in the input.

**EDIT**

I ended up using the custom validator solution provided below. The regex solution below did also work. As discussed, validators are the correct solution for this particular issue.

Comment: You can check it with custom validation also instead of regex..!

Comment: @RohitSharma I am using a dynamic form package and building a regex string is much easier from what I can tell.

Comment: @CAlex Creating validator would enable for easy reusability of it, it would also create more readable code and finally split it, thus easier testing. I too love regexp but they are for matching patterns, not whole words. Just take it into consideration

Comment: @Akxe that is a great point. Your solution is definitely the way it should be done. It doesn't exactly answer this particular question, but I think anyone viewing this thread with a similar question should go with a custom validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are preferring to look for a regex solution, you can use this regex to reject matches when it is exactly any one of these,

```
typescript
C#
python
```

The negative look ahead you wanted to use needs to be written like this,

```
^(?!(?:typescript|C#|python)$).+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IxeA6r/1)**

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Having a simple regex string is preferable to creating an entire custom validator in my case.

Comment: Is there a way to make this case-insensitive? I want any version of the word to fail as I am dealing with an insensitive database.

Comment: Yup. Just have this `(?i)` inline modifier before the regex and use this regex `(?i)^(?!(?:typescript|C#|python)$).+$` Or if you are using like this `/^(?!(?:typescript|C#|python)$).+/` then put `i` after last slash like this `/^(?!(?:typescript|C#|python)$).+/i`

Comment: I tried setting the i flag and it does not work, that was what I tried before I commented. It fails for any entry. I also tried the (?i) method and that throws an error. in the regex page you linked, it says "? The preceding token is not quantifiable"

Comment: It should've work though but seems like some syntax issue. Can you show some code you have by putting it in your post?

Comment: I see what is happening. The property of the form builder takes in a string for the pattern, and then transforms it. So `(?i)^(?!(?:Blue|Gold|White)$).+$` in turned into `/^(?i)^(?!(?:Blue|Gold|White)$).+$/` which will throw a syntax error. Nothing I can do about that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use regexp as it is quite an overkill, use [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators)

```ts
export function usedNames(validNames: string[]): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    if (validNames.includes(control.value)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { usedNames: {value: control.value} };
    }
  };
}
```

Usage (reactive form):

```ts
new FormGroup({
  'language': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
    Validators.required,
    usedNames(['typescript', 'C#', 'python']) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
  ]),
  // ... (other inputs)
});
```

Usage (template form):

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[appUsedNames]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: UsedNamesDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class UsedNamesDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('appUsedNames') usedNames: string;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
    return this.usedNames ? usedNames(this.usedNames)(control) : null;
  }
}
```

---

Also, you should think about making it `select` instead of `input` or add `list` & `<datalist>` to the input so that the user knows what he can type...